# How can I make an order with n:m associations?

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize.js for ORM, and I have some questions while I use it.

Models looks like this

```
var Keyword = db.define('keyword', {
  name: db.STRING,
});
var KeywordSearchableMap = db.define('keyword_searchable_map', {
  keyword_id: db.INTEGER,
  searchable: db.STRING,
  searchable_id: db.STRING,
  score: db.STRING,
});
var Searchable = db.define('searchable') {
  name: db.STRING,
});

Keyword.belongsToMany(Searchable, {
  through: {
    model: KeywordSearchableMap,
  },
  foreignKey: 'keyword_id'
});

Searchable.belongsToMany(Keyword, {
  through: {
    model: KeywordSearchableMap,
  },
  foreignKey: 'searchable_id'
});
```

And I want to get 'Searchable' things by Keyword.getSearchables() order by 'score' field in 'KeywordSearchableMap'

Is there any methods to get sorted searchable objects?